# Why RecyclerView is null?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, findviewbyid

I try to create a list of cards with info on it.
So, I have main activity, which starts card activity:

```
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.add_new_user) {            
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddNewUserActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);        
    } else if (id == R.id.view_rating) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,ViewAllPlayersActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
     }         
    return true;
}
```

ViewAllPlayersActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all_players);
    final RecyclerView    _recyclerView = (RecyclerView)   findViewById(R.id.activity_view_all_players);
// use a linear layout manager
final LinearLayoutManager    _layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    _recyclerView.setLayoutManager(_layoutManager); //null here

  
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    _recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    PlayerManager playerManager=new PlayerManager();
    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    _adapter = new ShowAllPlayersAdapter(playerManager.getAllPlayers());
    _recyclerView.setAdapter(_adapter);       
        }
    });
}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_view_all_players" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

And `content_view_all_players` layout file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_view_all_players"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="name1.name2.appname.ViewAllPlayersActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_view_all_players">

```
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/player_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

The problem is in that line:

```
 _recyclerView.setLayoutManager(_layoutManager); //null here
```

Why do I get null?
Can you help me?

P.S. I write `setContentView` before findViewbyId, bot now I have error:

> RecyclerView has no LayoutManager

Comment: You  called findViewById before setContentView

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setContentView` before `findViewById`.

Comment: some guy just told me never ever answer bad questions. :|

Comment: Didn't downvote, but an explanation why this is necessary would be a nice addition